# Get offset from timestamp in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how to get the offset from a timestamp. I'm in `France` so, for example, the offset of `26/10/2017` is `+2` but next week it will be `+1` so if I have a timestamp that is the date next week (with daylight time saving) how do I get this `+1`?

Thank you

Comment: Please change the tag sql-server to oracle.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select DATEPART(TZoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() ) / 60
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I dont succeed to get result from this command (im working with sql developer). Is this command suppose to return the offset associated to a given timestamp? I tried like this : select DATEPART(TZoffset, intervention.debutplage ) from intervention; where debutplage is my timestamp in intervention. I gor this error : 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: You can not use any column value for determining the current or next offset value. You have to use system date for getting the offset.

Comment: so there are no ways to get this offset from a given timestamp in base in oracle?

Comment: My answer was for sql-server. Could you correct the tag of your question?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any expertise about the Oracle